# MeanShift Clustering from csv file

Tags: python, csv, hierarchical-clustering, mean-shift

I have an csv file called age-average.
It has 4 column userId,average,age,count. I want to take average and age to cluster my users. Here is my code:

```
import csv
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.cluster import MeanShift
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_csv('/age-average.csv')
csv_file = open('/age-average.csv')
csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')
next(csv_reader)

for row in csv_reader:
    userID,average,age,count = row
    plt.scatter(age,average)

plt.show()
```

It shows the graph.So far everythink is ok. However when I must to use ms.fit() function I always get an error:

```
ms =  MeanShift()
ms.fit(df[['average','age']])
labels = ms.labels
cluster_centers = ms.cluster_centers_

print(cluster_centers)

n_clusters_ = len(np.unique(labels))

print("The number of estimated clusters ", n_clusters_)

colors = 10*['r.','g.','c.','k.','y.','m.']

print(colors)

for i in range(len(age,average)):
    plt.plot(int(age[i]), float(average[i]), colors[labels[i]], markersize = 10)
plt.scatter(cluster_centers[:,0],cluster_centers[:,1],
            marker="x", s= 150, linewidths = 5, zorder=10)
plt.show()
```

What should I write instead of df[['average','age']] inside of the ms.fit(). Can anybody have an idea? I get confused.
Thanks!

I got an error like

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "example.py", line 20, in
>   
>       labels = ms.labels AttributeError: 'MeanShift' object has no attribute 'labels'

Comment: maybe df[['average','age']].values? so you pass a numpy array instead a pandas object? Tough to say without seeing the error.

Comment: I edit my question I got an error like 'MeanShift' object has no attribute 'labels' when I try to use df[['average','age']].values as well

Comment: ms.fit takes two parameters: the list of features and the list of labels. You need to separate your data into a feature set (X) and a target label set (y).

Comment: I solved by convert df file to an np array by this on line code
`numpyMatrix = df.as_matrix()`
And put numpyMatrix on ms.fit like
`ms.fit(numpyMatrix)`